# How can I put an icon in the corner of a container ? (just get the icon)

Tags: flutter, icons

Exemple :

[image]

Reality :

[image]

I want that icon to be a "status" type of label, however with a Positioned it won't let me put it all the way to the left.

Is there any way to get the desired result or what other solution is there?

```
return ConstrainedBox(
  constraints: new BoxConstraints(
    minHeight: 50, //exemple
    minWidth: 100, //exemple
  ),
  child: Container(
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      color: Colors.orange,
    ),
    child: Stack(
      children: [
        Positioned(
          left: 0,
          top: 0,
          child: Transform.rotate(
            angle: -45 * pi / 180,
            child: Icon(
              Icons.arrow_drop_up,
              size: 30,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Center(
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: Text(
              "0001",
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 30,
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing the right way, But `Icon` comes with some extra spaces around it, *Green Color* allocate the size of Icon.

[image]

That's why you need to use negative value based on `iconSize` for `left` and `top` on `Positioned` widget.
It will be.

```dart
Positioned(
  left: -((12 * iconSize) / 30),
  top: -((13 * iconSize) / 30),
  child: Transform.rotate(
    angle: -45 * pi / 180,
    child: Icon(
      Icons.arrow_drop_up,
      size: iconSize,
    ),
  ),
),
```

And thanks to @Amir for the value, I am answering this question to have responsive view.

Comment: Thank you so much ! it works, I would just like to know why you divide it by 30 ?

Comment: It is a simple arithmetic logic to make responsive , I've forgotten the name of this method but `30` is icon's size that is working `12` and `13`,

Answer (score 1):

I changed the `left` and `top` numbers and icon went to top-left corner:

```dart
 Positioned(
     left: -12,
     top: -13,  
     child: ...
),
```

Result picture:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, it's also useful and helped me with the values!